# What is the difference between Kendo UI Core and Kendo UI Mobile?

Tags: kendo-ui, hybrid-mobile-app

I understand that Kendo UI mobile (15 controls) are included as part of Kendo UI core package, but I need to understand the difference. Can I use the kendo UI controls (non-mobile) to develop a SPA hybrid mobile app or I am only limited to the 15 mobile controls? So far my understanding is that I can use all of the 40+ but the mobile controls provides better data binding support and native rendering... Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mobile controls are built specifically for hybrid mobile applications.  That means that not only are they controls that you typically find on smaller screens (navbars, listviews, tabstrips, drawers), but there is an accompanying application object which "glues" together the application and provides view transitions.  Here is a simple example....

http://dojo.telerik.com/AvEF

The mobile framework also does a TON of heavy lifting in terms of taking care of meta tags, overflow scrolling, fast-click and touch support (no 300ms delay).

The SPA framework is abstracted from what the mobile application object uses.  So while you *could* use the SPA framework and web widgets to build your hybrid app, Kendo UI Mobile was designed for exactly this, so you would be much better off with Kendo UI Mobile.

Also - if you're doing hybrid, you may want to checkout [AppBuilder](http://www.telerik.com/platform#overview) which provides Kendo UI Mobile as the default UI library.