# Kendo Mobile/Hybird Widgets and ARIA Accessibility

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, telerik, accessibility, kendo-mobile

Some background information: I would like to build a **fully accessible** (wai-aria) **mobile-first** app using Kendo.

I know that Kendo UI has built in accessibility for web widgets, I can see when I inspect the demo versions of the buttons, etc, that all of the aria roles are predefined and set for me:
http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/accessibility/wai-aria-support-in-kendo

However I fail to see the same thing happening when I inspect Kendo Hybird widgets:
http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/hybrid/introduction

If hybird widgets do not have built in wai-aria accessibility, what are my options for building a performant, cross-platform mobile first app with kendo (alternative is maybe jquery mobile)?

Do I have to use a SPA framework with web widgets? Or should I just use the web-widgets within the hybird application? Either way, performance and cross-compatibility betweeen android, ios, web are key factors, and would like to know how these will be affected.

Would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: My initial reason for choosing kendo hybird seen in the answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24533008/what-is-the-difference-between-kendo-ui-core-and-kendo-ui-mobile

Comment: I'm not familiar with Kendo, but there is more to accessibility than just ARIA. Aria only helps some screenreader users; but for full accessibility you will also need to consider keyboard, colour, understandability, etc. I see some notes on this in the Kendo docs, although they promote the outdated accesskey attribute so may not be reliable. Their ARIA does look good though, so maybe you can copy the attributes used in the UI version to your hybrid version.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and advice! I understand Aria can be extensive, but I'm trying to find a moble-first framework/Ui set with the most accessibility features out-of-box (for a enterprise client that values this first). I feel this would reduce the risks of aria errors later down the road. If anyone else can guide me on Kendo, I would be very grateful. Alternatively I was looking at foundation for sites (in addition to jquery mobile).